# Extracting Data from Text file in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to extract data from .txt file. I need to extract Group Number,Subscriber Id,Name and Address (your network) from different .txt files.

The data in the text files are extracted using flexireader ocr from an insurance cards

```
sample Text file 1:
---------------------
Subscriber ID: AH0002305 
PAUL KELLERMAN
Medical plan: PPO 
Group number: L16788344 
Allied 
Pharmacy benefit: CVS Caremark 
RXBIN: 004336 
RXPCN: ADV 
RXGRP: RX4219 
ORX mail order: 
855.566.8393 
Pharmacy help desk: 
800.364.6331 
a remark.com 

Sample Text file 2:
----------------------
 • 
'11, • 
cStarmark 
A Morn, a k ompam 
Employee 
Member: JOHN ABRUZZ 
ID: 3780-1290 Mem Eff: 09/01/2016 
Group ID: MF873078E 
Employer: MINDFLOW 
INC 
Copay: OV $40 \ UC $85 \ ER $500 
Ded: $3000 \ $6000 Fam Ded: $6000 \ $12000 
Coins: 80% \ 60% 
Claims Submission 
Aetna partopa ing 
EDI: 61425 
Mail: Starmark 
P.O. Box 2942 
Clinton, IA 52733-2942 
• • t. doctors and hospitals are independent 
providers and are neither agents nor employees of Aetna. 
Self-funded Plan Administered by Starmark 
llr 
Pharmacy Vendor 
CVS/caremark 
877-876-7217 
RxID: 32149890C 
RxBIN: 004336 
RxPCN: ADV 
RxGRP: RX0022 
ISSUER: 80840 
Ded: $0 Copay: $15 \ $45 \ $75 
Medical PPO Network 
Aetna Signature 
Administrators' PPO 
By aetna 
To locate a PPO provider: 
 www.aetna.com/asa 
 800-522-1246
```

Main problem for me is , in one file it is subscriber ID , other file it is mentioned as Member ID, How can i considered them as same , Can any one can help me with this. I am a intern developer, I don't have much experience on C#.

I tried this code but it is matching the pattern

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\Kumar\Desktop\Insurance text\Previous.out.txt";
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    String str = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(str, "Subscriber ID"))
                        buffer.Append(str + "\n");  
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(buffer.ToString());
             Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: As to me, you have to create two different methods to parse text file depending on its content.

Comment: I think the key, as you say is "one file" vs. anther.  If the files aren't too long, write a function to validate FILE_TYPE (if contains fields, etc.) and then pass it to the method to parse, as per Marcie's suggestion.  If you can do fancy regex later, then all is not lost - you can still update the functions.

Comment: `if (Regex.IsMatch(str, "Subscriber ID|Member ID"))`

Comment: Since the names used are characters from "Prison Break", hopefully it is not real information

Comment: To be honest it's probably impractical bordering on impossible to extract the data you need from these files because they weren't designed to follow any consistent format. If you could somehow account for every scenario then the very next file might contain something different.

Comment: @RufusL these are my insurance cards, I dont want to reveal my original insurance card info, so I took some names from my fav series.

Comment: @ScottHannen , yes it doesn't follow any consistency of data , our team using ABBY FINE READER OCR , to extract data from different type of insurance cards. So we are getting the data in different forms. I need to write a single code to read and print data for the data from different insurance cards

Answer (score 0):

> in one file it is subscriber ID , other file it is mentioned as Member ID, How can i considered them as same

One would write a mapping function, but consider the data as just an `id` and then associate the data in the main program after reading in the *entities*, and storing both variables.

> I am trying to extract data from .txt file. I need to extract Group Number,Subscriber Id,Name and Address (your network) from different .txt files.

You will need to write two different processes to extract the data. Using two different regular expressions for each one.